# How to download a file in react js from an url

Tags: javascript, reactjs, download

I tried several ways to download a file from URL. Eventhough it is downloading, I couldn't able to view the file. It is showing, the file is not supported

Comment: If it's downloading but you can't open it then either the file is corrupt or you don't have an app on your device that can open it. Doesn't sound like a React issue.

Comment: If I open that URL in a separate tab on my browser, it is downloading and I can able to view the file. I tried this URL https://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf. But, when I tried to download a file from this URL programatically, it is not working as expected